# Single Column Appendix in twocolumn article

Tags: two-column, appendices, article

My article uses the `twocolumn` parameter of the `article` document class. However I want to list my images as a multipage appendix at the end of the document (in a new page) but I want a single column appendix so that I can center my figures properly.

I have tried to use the `minipage` environment inside `\twocolumn [  ]` but it does not seem to work. Take a look at the code:

```
%document body, packages etc.
\newpage

\section*{Appendix}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{curve1}
  \caption{An arbitrary initial poinset $\mathbb{S}^2$.}
    \label{curve1}
\end{figure}
%figure curve 1



\end{minipage}


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

For instance, the figure does not appear to be rendered and the error which is returned by the compiler is:

`Not in outer par mode`

Comment: Remove the `minipage` and the `center` environments and issue `\onecolumn` just before `\section*{Appendix}`. Also add `\centering` just after `\begin{figure}`

Comment: In APS templates, which are two-column articles, you need to do `\onecolumngrid` instead of `\onecolumn`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error you get is due to the fact that you're embedding a floating environment like `figure` in a `minipage` and this is not allowed.

To achieve what you want, when you are in a two-column document, simply issuing the command

```
\onecolumn
```

puts you in one-column mode.

Also, to have centered contents inside the `figure`, use `\centering` instead of a `center` environment.

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\section{main}
\lipsum[1-5]

\onecolumn

\section*{Appendix}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{curve1}
  \caption{An arbitrary initial poinset $\mathbb{S}^2$.}
    \label{curve1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Just tried this out with the IEEEtran.cls template and works great. Thank you!