# elsevier 5p document make a single column page in document

Tags: two-column, elsarticle

I have a document using the `elsarticle` with `\documentclass[5p]{ elsarticle}`. Which is fine for the main document body. However, for an appendix I need a single column page, but have been unable to find out how to do this. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So I did not realise that `elsarticle` is based on `article`. So what I should have searched for was a solution for the `article` document class.

The solution is to use `\onecolumn` as presented in this answer: [Single Column Appendix in twocolumn article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230256/single-column-appendix-in-twocolumn-article).